# Adding a New Column Based on Statistics to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, statistics

this is my first question. I want to build a statistical model. I have a data and I want to add a column to this dataframe. I want this column to show some statistical things.
For example my dataframe is like this

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tGAl.png)

For example, I want to add a new column. I want this column to show "car red girl"s D value is more than the mean of all car's D. How should I do this? Which way should I use to do this statistical model. I have a large data and I can't calculate the all car's or bike's mean manually. I need a function with if-else statements and adding a column to describe is the row's D more or less than mean.

My code is like this, but I am getting Key Error 0.

```
for b in list(df.A.unique()):
    for i in range(len(df.loc[df.A == b])):
        if df.loc[df.A == b, "D"][i] >= df.loc[df.A == b,"D"].mean():
            df.loc[df.A== b]["E"][i] = "Bigger"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages / DataFrame`. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

This can fairly be achieved using `pandas` library. Assuming, your `DataFrame` is stored in the variable `df`.

Step 1 - Calculate Mean of the column

Step 2 - Get Indices Where Column Value is greater than column Mean

Step 3 - Set Value in those indices to True

```
mean_D=df.loc[:,"D"].mean()
df.loc[:,"E"]=False #Set Initially to 'False' implying D's mean is less than column mean
indices=df[df.loc[:,"D"]>mean_D].index
df.loc[indices,"E"]=True
```

**EDIT 1**

1. Store the Individual Mean in a dictionary
2. Compute corresponding indices where value greater than mean (individually)
3. Set the indices as `True`

```
from collections import defaultdict
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['car','car','car','bike','bike','bike'],"B":['red','red','blue','black','white','red'],"C":['girl','boy','boy','boy','girl','girl'],"D":[8,7,6,9,10,7]})
dict_car_bike=defaultdict(list)
for i, temp in df.groupby("A"):
    dict_car_bike[temp.loc[:,"A"].unique()[0]]=temp.loc[:,"D"].mean()

dict_car_bike=dict(dict_car_bike)

df.loc[:,"E"]=False #Set Initially to 'False' implying D's mean is less than column mean
indices_0=df[(df.A.astype(str)==list(dict_car_bike.keys())[0]) & (df.D>dict_car_bike[list(dict_car_bike.keys())[0]])].index
indices_1=df[(df.A==list(dict_car_bike.keys())[1]) & (df.D>dict_car_bike[list(dict_car_bike.keys())[1]])].index
df.loc[indices_0,"E"]=True
df.loc[indices_1,"E"]=True
```

**OUTPUT**

`Output DataFrame`

```
     A      B     C    D      E
0   car    red  girl   8   True
1   car    red   boy   7  False
2   car   blue   boy   6  False
3  bike  black   boy   9   True
4  bike  white  girl  10   True
5  bike    red  girl   7  False
```

`Output Dictionary with Corresponding Mean`

```
{'bike': 8.666666666666666, 'car': 7.0}
```

Comment: Hey Anant, thank for answering. Probably I couldn't explain myself rightly. Your code is working yes but not the way I wanted. For example, in my example data mean of Car's D 7, I want new column based on Car's mean. Mean of Bike's 8.6 and I want new column based on Bike's mean. I hope you can help me on this way too.

Comment: Hey Anant, thanks for answering again. But as I told in the post, I have a very large data and I should build a statistical model. So I can not compute means individually :/